# Concatenate multiple columns into one column (~) separated

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query

```
select DISTINCT(a.col1),b.col2
FROM tab1 a RIGHT OUTER JOIN  tab2 b
ON a.tab1_id=b.tab2_id
WHERE
a.tab1_id=105
```

Getting output as

```
col1           col2
______________________
A               val1
A               val2
```

I want to concatenate the above result in one value `~` separated

eg.  `A~val1~val2`

Please guide

Comment: How big is your table, and how big can the resultset be? What have you tried? Which version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Query:

```
SELECT a.col1+'~'+       
       STUFF((
        SELECT '~' + s2.col2
        FROM tab1 s1
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN tab2 s2 ON s1.tab1_id=s2.tab2_id
        WHERE a.col1 = s1.col1
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, '')  AS columns2
FROM tab1 a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tab2 b ON a.tab1_id=b.tab2_id
WHERE a.tab1_id=105
GROUP BY a.col1
```

Example Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d517/2)**

```
SELECT
s.col1+'~'+
STUFF((
        SELECT '~' + col2
        FROM Table1 s2
        WHERE s2.col1 = s.col1
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, '')  AS columns2
FROM Table1 s
GROUP BY s.col1
```

Result:

```
|    COLUMNS2 |
---------------
| A~val1~val2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT(b.col2 SEPARATOR '~')`

Entire Query:

```
select a.col1, GROUP_CONCAT(b.col2 SEPARATOR '~') AS grouped
FROM tab1 a RIGHT OUTER JOIN  tab2 b
ON a.tab1_id=b.tab2_id
WHERE
a.tab1_id=105
GROUP BY a.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you may use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
select a.col1, GROUP_CONCAT(b.col2,'/')
FROM tab1 a RIGHT OUTER JOIN  tab2 b
ON a.tab1_id=b.tab2_id
WHERE
a.tab1_id=105
GROUP BY a.col1
```

In MySQL Server you may use `CROSS Apply` or `Stuff` or even this simple `Xml Path for`. Perhaps you have gotten answers. But here you go, easier. The sample table can be treated as the result of your joined query without conditions like col1 = 1.. Please incorporate your joined table strucuture withing the following query.

Sample Table:

```
COL1    COL2
1       john
2       tim
1       jack
3       rose
```

Query:

```
SELECT col1, replace
((SELECT col2 AS [data()]
FROM tab1
WHERE  col1 = a.col1
ORDER BY col1 FOR xml path('')), ' ','/')
FROM  tab1 a
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
AND col1 = 1
GROUP BY col1
;
```

Results: my keyboard doesn't have the particular character you need. You may replace the forward slash ;) with it

```
COL1    COLUMN_1
1       john/jack
```

### * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0403a/1)

Comment: @Edward here is another method. You may want to use your joined table strucutre within where I have used a single table for the sample. But it sure makes things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Result as a single string output, please try:

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @output =COALESCE( @output + '~', Col1+'~')+Col2 FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT(a.col1) Col1,b.col2 Col2
    FROM tab1 a RIGHT OUTER JOIN  tab2 b
    ON a.tab1_id=b.tab2_id
    WHERE
    a.tab1_id=105
)x
GROUP BY Col1,Col2

SELECT @output
```